# How to include variable session into a default value of a route parameter on Symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony, session, routes

I am using Symfony 4 for one of my project and here is my problem :

#### Actual Behavior :

In one of my controller's action, I am using a place given by the user to return some data around this place.
To do that, this "place" parameter is required into the route that launched this action.
If no parameter is given, this "place" parameter has a default value set to "partout" (means "everywhere")

#### What I want to achieve :

Instead of giving the "partout" default value, I would like to check into the session variables the last place entered by this user and use it as default value.
I know how to get the last place entered into a session variable but I do not know how to check it before routing and insert it as default value.

Do you have any idea on how can I achieve that the most properly ?

Please find below a preview of my controller's action :

```
/**
 * @Route("/{sport}/{match}_{program_id}/{place}/{page}", name="show_game", defaults={"place":"partout","page":1},requirements={"program_id"="\d+","page"="\d+"})
 * @param Request $request
 * @param $sport
 * @param $match
 * @param $program_id
 * @param $place
 * @return Response Response as a instance
 */
public function showGame(Request $request,$sport,$match, $program_id, $place,$page)
{...}
```

Comment: why do you have to check it before routing?
one thing is not clear .. currently, as explained in the Actual Behavior, you have already created the structure to pass the place value to the function and only if nothing is passed is 'partout' set by default?

Or do you miss this part? (pass the value to 'place' when calling the route)

Comment: If you really wanted to do this then I suppose a kernel request listener might work: https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html But I'm a bit skeptical that you really need this.

Comment: You can always check if $place is null/empty and then use `$session = $request->getSession();`  `$session->get('place');` to get the value from the session

Comment: @Nobady Yes I already have the structure. I can effectively pass the value 'place' with the correct value from variable session when calling the route. This is what I am doing right now. But I still have an issue when the user enter the url in his navigator without setting any place... because in that case I can only check his session variables once my controller's action is executed and, for example, if its previous place was Paris I will then return data around Paris but I wont get "paris"in the url because the "check" would be done after the routing... Tell me if it is not clear enough !